# how to Unit test fluent mappings, with in memory sqlite when you got sequences

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

My Real db is oracle, and has sequences(not under my control).
I wanna test the mappings with in memory sqlite db,
I thought about a few options, do a sequence conventions(if possible) that will be active only when I'm on oracle, make the Id Mapping call another method that will resolve the id mapping by it self and ask some one about the configured db.

What is the best practice for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `GenretedBy.Native([seqName]);`